Ecto - how to select both the sum of a group and the overall sum in a query?
Given I have a table with the following schema where date is non-unique:
defmodule Record do
  field(:plays, :integer)
  field(:date, :date) 
end

I want to select both the sum of plays per group, and the overall sum of plays of all records:
query =
  Record
  |> group_by([r], [r.date])
  |> select([r], %{
    date: r.date, 
    total_plays_per_date: fragment("coalesce(sum(?), 0)", r.plays),
    overall_total_plays: # Sum of all plays from all records
  })


SQL and relational databases don't easily support this, and it doesn't map well to Ecto either.  In the syntax you're showing you're trying to include the overall total in the map record for each entry.  The syntax to do this would be awkward, and it's probably easier to just compute the overall sum in your application code.
import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]
query = from r in Record,
          group_by: r.date,
          select: %{
            date: r.date,
            total_plays_per_date: sum(r.plays)
          }
all_plays = Repo.all(query)
overall_total_plays = all_plays |> Enum.map(& &1.total_plays_per_date) |> Enum.sum()

If you did need to include this in each record you could then add it in after the fact
all_plays = Enum.map(all_plays, &Map.put(&1, :overall_total_plays, overall_total_plays))

